# HTTPS express.js server and routes

Tags: https, express, ssl-certificate

I just changed my server to use HTTPS. I have a very boiler plate code. When I go to localhost:8888, the browser hangs and my route never gets called. Curl from the command line is the same.

I am wondering I am defining my route incorrectly.
THe code is the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');        

var https = require('https');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');



// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8888);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);

//app.use(logErrors);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


var options = { 
        key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'), 
        cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')};




app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);


https.createServer(options, app.handle).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Anyone sees what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want just `app` where you have `app.handle`:

```
https.createServer(options, app)....
```

Also note for cURL testing you'll need to do `curl --insecure https://localhost:8888` since you are presumably using a non-commercial self-signed certificate which neither curl nor browsers will trust without a user explicit override.

Comment: no change when I change to app, per your suggestion. curl --insecure https://localhost:8888
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:8888

Comment: I would suggest getting your routes working over HTTP first and then just making surgical changes to switch to HTTPS so your problem scope is limited. The curl error indicates perhaps your certificate files aren't correct? Hard to debug since I think the code you posted looks reasonable. I use nginx to terminate TLS and avoid this whole unnecessary headache.

Comment: my routes work fine correctly until I switched over to HTTPS.

Comment: I regenerated the certificates and now everything is working. I did not have to change a thing about the routes

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to `https://localhost:8888`.

The browser can't automatically figure out that you're listening for SSL connections on that port.